# escaping ampersands in UIBinder (adbrite script)

Tags: javascript, gwt, uibinder

I need to integrate the following script inside a div in UIBinder:

```
 <!-- Begin: adBrite, Generated: 2011-04-14 8:40:27  -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var AdBrite_Title_Color = '66B5FF';
 var AdBrite_Text_Color = '000000';
 var AdBrite_Background_Color = 'FFFFFF';
 var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'CCCCCC';
 var AdBrite_URL_Color = '008000';
 try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
 </script>
 <span style="white-space:nowrap;"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=123&zs=123&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));</script>
 <a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=123&afsid=1"><img src="http://files.adbrite.com/mb/images/adbrite-your-ad-here-leaderboard.gif" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;border:none;padding:0;margin:0;" alt="Your Ad Here" width="14" height="90" border="0" /></a></span>
 <!-- End: adBrite -->
```

The GWT compiler complains about the ampersands, so I changed them to `&amp;`.

I've also taken care to declare the following at the top of my file so that the ampersand entity can be properly resolved:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
```

This at least allows me to compile the code, but the resulting page renders with `&amp;` instead of `&`, which of course breaks the script.

How can I properly escape the ampersands so that the script runs properly? Is there a way to declare this script in my loader html/jsp, and have it render into a div of my choosing? I couldn't find much documentation on Adbrite's site.

And lastly, is it truly necessary for Adbrite to try and hide the fact that the script is coming from a remote site with the `String.fromCharCode` nonsense? Presumably this is being done to prevent some kind of XSS filtering from kicking in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your Javascript code between HTML comments.
Replace `&` by `&amp;`.

Here is the code with the corrections:

```
<!-- Begin: adBrite, Generated: 2011-04-14 8:40:27 -->
        <script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
            var AdBrite_Title_Color = '66B5FF';
            var AdBrite_Text_Color = '000000';
            var AdBrite_Background_Color = 'FFFFFF';
            var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'CCCCCC';
            var AdBrite_URL_Color = '008000';
            try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var
            AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var
            AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
  --></script>

 <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--  document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=123&zs=123&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62)); --></script>
 <a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=123&amp;afsid=1"><img src="http://files.adbrite.com/mb/images/adbrite-your-ad-here-leaderboard.gif" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;border:none;padding:0;margin:0;" alt="Your Ad Here" width="14" height="90" border="0" /></a></span>
        <!-- End: adBrite -->
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to help. Looking at the resulting DOM, I get an empty script tag, and then the anchor for the image has \u0026 in the URL. You realize that this is UIBinder in GWT, not just plain HTML, right?  Sorry if I was unclear in my question.

Comment: Yes, I did the test using UIBinder in GWT. And it worked fine. I think it can be something related to the enconding charset being used. I did this test using UTF-8 encoding for the files and in the HTML header:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
Try that.

Comment: No problem with the script tag empty in the DOM. The script will run fine.


Which encoding charset are you using in the project files and in the HTML header of your GWT project?

Comment: I already have the meta tag you suggested in place. The placeholder image comes up ("your ad here") but the actual ad does not. When you tried this did you get \u0026 in the DOM?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're right. I get \u0026 in the DOM. Use &amp; instead. In my case, it worked, and was replaced by &. Clicking in the "your ad here" image is working know.

Comment: I created an empty HTML page with your code and the only thing I can see is the "your ad here" image. There's no additional ad.

Comment: The & -> &amp; replacement works for the anchor tag, but not for the embedded script. I think GWT is somehow not smart enough to do the substitution on the string, so the 'zs' and 'ifr' params are not being properly set. I think you are not seeing actual ads in the HTML page because I sanitized the params for 'sid' and 'zs'; when I use real values, and host in an HTML page, I get ads. Sorry if that led to confusion, but I didn't want someone copy/pasting this code block and causing issues with our Adbrite ID. I'm experimenting with using JSNI to set the script content, but no solution yet.