# Same Origin Policy and external scripts

Tags: javascript, xss, same-origin-policy

I've been tasked with integrating ad code from AdBrite.

This is the snippet I've been given, sanitized to remove our identifiers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AdBrite_Title_Color = '3D81EE';
var AdBrite_Text_Color = '000000';
var AdBrite_Background_Color = 'FFFFFF';
var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'CCCCCC';
var AdBrite_URL_Color = '008000';
try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=sanitized&zs=sanitized&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));</script>
<div><a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=sanitized&afsid=1" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Your Ad Here</a></div>
```

It's loading a remote script from the Adbrite servers by writing to the DOM. The `String.fromCharCode` cleverly writes out the ASCII chars for `<script>` in order to reference the remote Javascript file.

**My question is: why does this work? Don't browsers recognize this as a violation of the Same Origin Policy?**

BTW, what prompted my investigation of this was the fact that I'm having [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667781/escaping-ampersands-in-uibinder-adbrite-script/5669123#comment-6497938) getting the URL params to be properly escaped and then un-escaped in GWT's UIBinder.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same origin policy applies to AJAX requests. Loading remote scripts is not governed by this rule, hence solutions like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) might exists.

Comment: OK, but then why is AdBrite obfuscating it with the String.fromCharCode?

Comment: I believe it might be a workaround for some older browsers misinterpreting a `<script>` tag inside the quotes. Not sure, though.

Comment: See also [Part 2](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Life_outside_same-origin_rules) of the [Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main).

Comment: Hmm, I think what's going in with the String.fromCharCode() is that they're using this to dynamically set the url params, and they're escaping <script> so that the browser doesn't try and interpret it as a script on the "first pass", so to speak. Thanks, Xion & idealmachine.